# Large adjacent creature and a reach weapon, can you attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, reach

When you are medium, have a reach weapon, and are adjacent to a large creature, are you allowed to make an attack on the parts of the creature that are further away?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strict RAW would say no:

> **Reach:** You use a reach weapon to strike opponents 10 feet away, but you *can't use it against an adjacent foe*. ([source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#wpn-quality-reach); emphasis mine)

Since the large creature is adjacent, a reach weapon can't be used against it.

Comment: This was the same logic I used when I told the player no. Im glad you had a rule to back me up, thank you.

Comment: while i agree with what the rules say, it seems like this is a one sided way of looking at things. I would say that a large creature standing next to the character can be both adjacent and 10'away at the same time, as 'hey I Can Chan' says

Comment: My kneejerk reaction is not this answer, but actually considering it realistically, I can see how this also makes real sense, not just rules sense.

Answer (score 1):

If parts of the creature is 10' away, it would make sense that You could attack that area if there is nothing blocking your weapon. So I would say yes

Comment: This was my thinking, too. I read the quotation in the answer from @minnmass and thought *But parts of my opponent are* both *10 ft. away* and *adjacent!* I *know* that thinking's erroneous (formal logic probably somehow proving it), but, if it isn't, my temptation would be to have the attacked Large creature's 10-ft.-away square be considered affected by [cover](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Cover)... gained from the creature itself. (This would also make impossible attacks of opportunity against that creature's square using this technique.)

Comment: The quote is correct but sometimes the rules don't always fully cover a situation. Like you said the creature is both adjacent and 10' away. So unless it can push the reach weapon away with an appendage that is within that 10' it would seem that an attack is possible. Cover seems a good way to mitigate the threat.